# Flash/ajax file upload to blobstore?

Tags: google-app-engine, uploadify, blobstore

Is it possible to use some enhanced component to upload files to blobstore?

I'm playing with uploadify but facing problems to put it to work. I would like to be able to filter the kind of file before send it to blobstore, as well as the file size and maybe show some progress bar during the upload...

PS: For those who also subscribe the gae-j group, this is a reposting, since nobody answered this question in the group...

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/index.php), which does pretty much everything you are looking for, and also [this post](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/Implementing-a-dropbox-service-with-the-Blobstore-API-part-2), which demonstrates how to implement Plupload using App Engine.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Didn't try yet, but according to the post, it should work!

Comment: Just updating the topic, unfortunately the code in the post seems to be not working to me. I'm using Java instead of Phyton. The request is bypassed from blobstore to my code, which executes, but the redirect my code sends, seems to be not reaching the plupload plugin...